# OptimisticLockException in simple Java SE update code

Tags: java, jpa

I'm hitting a problem that I don't know how to solve (and, as usual, it is probably a silly fault on my side). I'm writing a Java SE Swing application using Embedded Derby and JPA (EclipseLink). No multiuser, although I can open several tabbedpanes to perform different operations. However, in this problem I'm using a single pane to reproduce the problem.

In that test panel, whenever I add it as tabbed pane, I run this code:

```
public void onTabPanelAdded() {
    if (entityManager == null) {
        // emf is a static property in the Main class
        // so I just create one EntityManagerFactory,
        // but one EntityManager for each JPanel
        entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    selectedL10n = entityManager.find(L10n.class, 1);
    l10nCodeField.setText(selectedL10n.getCode());
    descripField.setText(selectedL10n.getName());
    l10nCodeField.requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

Whenever I close the tabbed pane (hiding the JPanel), I run this code:

```
public void onTabPanelRemoved() {
    if (entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    entityManager.close();
    entityManager = null;
}
```

although the error is happening before closing/hiding the JPanel (just to relieve you from thinking it has to do with not releasing the EntityManager).

Now, the test panel, as you see in the first block of code, retrieves a persisted entity from the DB and fills the TextFields in the panel. After making a simple change in the data and clickin the Save button I put in it, this code is run:

```
private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    selectedL10n = entityManager.merge(selectedL10n);
    selectedL10n.setCode(l10nCodeField.getText());
    selectedL10n.setName(descripField.getText());
    try {
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(L10nGUIManager.class.getName()).log(
            Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

As you see, I open the transaction, merge the entity to make sure it is managed (I've double-checked this by using entityManager.contains(selectedL10n)), apply the changes and commit. And yet, despite no other part of the application and no other instances/users are using it, I get an OptimisticLockException. I simply don't understand it.

The entity has an annotated version field:

```
@Entity
public class L10n implements Serializable, Comparable<L10n> {
@Version
private int entityVersion;
...
```

with his corresponding getter/setter. I am absolutely lost about the reason.

TIA

Comment: Not an expert so posting as a comment - I see `flush` is *Synchronize the persistence context to the underlying database.* while `commit` is *Commit the current resource transaction, **writing any unflushed changes** to the database.* - I suspect you do not want to do both, or if you do you should use `commit` then `flush`.

Comment: Thanks, OldCurmudgeon. I have not used flush() in this code and I have not generally used it across my application. I hope that's not the reason of this error, because otherwise I would have to review all the application. :-)

Comment: *I have not used flush() in this code* - er ... yes you have - `onTabPanelRemoved ... entityManager.flush();`

Comment: Oops... Yes, you're right. But the error happens before the onTabPanelRemoved is executed, as I told. The onTabPanelRemoved code is there just to show that the error is not due to conflicts with leaving the EntityManager open and trying to create a new one on removing/readding the tabpane.